# how to close tabs ads in selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I Want to scrape a website with many ads when the code click on any thing a new advertisement appear and I want to close this tabs I try to use this way:

```
MainWindow = driver.current_window_handle
Windows = driver.window_handles
for window in Windows:
    driver.switch_to.window(window)
    if MainWindow != driver.current_window_handle:
        driver.close()

print(driver.title)
```

it give me that error:

```
File "D:\yossef\python\projects\telegram_bot\package\egybest.py", line 245, in download_series
    print(self.driver.title)
File "D:\yossef\python\projects\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 342, in title
    resp = self.execute(Command.GET_TITLE)
File "D:\yossef\python\projects\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "D:\yossef\python\projects\telegram_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: no such window: target window already closed from unknown error: web view not found   (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 driver.switch_to_window(window)
```

has been deprecated.

try

```
driver.switch_to.window(window)
```

and see if that helps. Also, I would suggest to put some sleep before closing the windows.